# showing a ring is isomorphic to a localization of $R$ at $S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, localization

> Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field. The domain of $f = \frac{g}h\in \mathbb{K}(x), $ where $g,h\in \mathbb{K}[x]$ is defined to be the set $Dom(f) := \{c\in \mathbb{K} : h(c) \neq 0\}.$ Let $S(c) := \{f\in \mathbb{K}(x) : c\in Dom(f)\}$ for $c\in \mathbb{K}.$
> Show that for every $c\in \mathbb{K},$ $\mathbb{K}[x]_{(x-c)}\cong S(c),$ where $(x-c)$ is the smallest ideal of $\mathbb{K}[x]$ containing $x-c$ and $\mathbb{K}[x]_{(x-c)}$ is the localization of $\mathbb{K}[x]$ with respect to $(x-c)$ and its elements can be thought of as fractions with numerators in $\mathbb{K}[x]$ and denominators in $\mathbb{K}[x]\backslash (x-c).$

I know that localizations are unique in the sense that if $R$ is a commutative ring, $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $R$, and $Q$ is a commutative ring so that there exists an injective homomorphism $\phi : R\to Q$ so that

1. $\phi(x)$ is a unit of $Q$ for every $x\in S$ and every element of $Q$ is of the form $\phi(x)\phi(y)^{-1}$ for $x\in R, y\in S$
2. If $\psi : R\to T$ is a morphism so that $\psi(x)$ is a unit of $T$ for all $x\in S,$ there exists a morphism $\tilde{\psi} : Q\to T$ so that $\tilde{\psi}\circ \phi = \psi,$

then $Q$ is isomorphic to the localization of $R$ at $S.$ So I think one way to prove part $3$ is to show these two conditions are satisfied for $S(c).$

Alternatively, is there a more "direct" approach to this problem? I was thinking of defining the map $\phi : \mathbb{K}[x]_{(x-c)}\to S(c), \phi(\frac{a}b) = \frac{a}b$. However, it seems that showing that this map is an isomorphism would also show that $S(c) = \mathbb{K}[x]_{(x-c)}.$ I know $S(c)$ is a subring of $\mathbb{K}(x)$ and hence is commutative. Let $R = \mathbb{K}[x], S = \mathbb{K}[x]\backslash (x-c).$ Define $\phi : R\to S(c)$ as follows. $\phi(x) = \frac{x}1.$ Observe that this map is clearly injective. Since for $f=g/h\in S(c), h(c)\neq 0, h\not\in (x-c)\Rightarrow h\in S.$ So $f = \phi(g)\phi(h)^{-1}.$ Then define $\tilde{\psi} : S(c)\to T$ so that $\tilde{\psi}(\frac{a}b) = \psi(a)\psi(b)^{-1}.$ Then one can verify that $\tilde{\psi}$ has the required properties.

Comment: What is $S(c)$?

Comment: @CHENRK I updated the question.

Comment: Why does $\phi$ have to be injective? It's possible to build localizations $S^{-1}R$ for a commutative unital ring $R$ for which $\phi:R \to S^{-1}R$ is not injective (just include $0 \in S$, for instance, and assume that $\lvert R \rvert \geq 2$).

Comment: Despite this issue, you have the correct idea! To show $K[x]_{(x-c)} \cong S(c)$ you need to construct your map $\phi:K[x] \to S(c)$ and then show that $S(c)$ has properties (1) and (2) above (note, however, that you also need to ask for the morphism $\overline{\psi}$ to be unique).

Comment: @Geoff is there some easier way that gives a "direct" isomorphism between the two rings?